# Any way to allow one statement (or is it a chunk?) from a string in lua?

Tags: lua

Is there any way to allow one statement from a Lua code (string)?

For example:

1. OK

   "AddTwo(1, 3) + 9 + RandomValue(1, 3)"
2. NOT OKAY

   "AddTwo(1, 3) + 9 + RandomValue(1, 3)  SomeGlobalVariable = 1"

   "AddTwo(1, 3) + 9 + RandomValue(1, 3)  function HeyImNewFunction() return [[Hello!]] end"

Since semicolon is optional, those NOT OKAY examples could be two statements in Lua.

Oh and the version is Lua 5.1!

Comment: Why are you trying to parse strings like this into Lua code? We will be able to give you better advice if we know what your end goal is.

Comment: @JackTaylor I'm loading various lua statements to my program (C# w/ MoonSharp). There will be various statements across a json file. These statements are loaded one by one via a json parser during runtime and called whenever needed. I want one item to have only one statement because it should return a value but NEVER allow anything else more. Hope that helped.

Comment: Are these strings user-supplied? In other words, can you expect them to contain any malicious code? (Judging from your description I'm guessing that the answer is "yes", but it's good to make sure.)

Comment: @JackTaylor yeah, that's why I'm concerned about codes being injected.

Answer (score 3):

Since a statement can be a compound statement such as a `do...end` block, you cannot identify "simple" statements without a parser.

If you want *expressions* instead of statements, then appending the string after `return` will only be valid Lua code if the string contains a list of expressions. This may be enough for your purposes. At least it works for the examples you gave.

Comment: That's what I'm doing. The only problem is people can inject custom codes by having something like, "3; end function injectedFunction() do malicious stuff end injectedFunction(); function dummy() return nil;"  // "end" omitted because the program will append it.

Comment: @user6516781 But they could also write `3 + io.popen("kill -9 -1")`.  Even though the statement will fail because of type mismatch the `popen` part is evaluated and pwnes your system.

Comment: @user6516781, you need to run user-supplied code in a sandbox that restricts which functions are available and how much time and memory is allowed.